# Black screen issue while calling another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In my main activity i have  5 image views.By clicking each image it should navigate the activity to another.But my problem is while clicking an image it is showing the same activity once and then black screen for sometime and then only it is showing the second activity. I googled this but i don't know how to rectify this..
so far i have tried

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View View)
        {
         {    
  Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, activity1.class);
        //intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
             //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                             overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
                startActivity(intent);

             /* Intent i = new Intent(main.this, activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);   */
              // startActivity(new Intent(main.this, activity1.class)));
          }
```

but nothing worked for me.. help me in resolving this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: why you pass second intent and in which class u pass this what u want to do dear

Comment: remove flag_activity_new_mask and remove override pending transaction.

Comment: @HarshitRathi i removed that and i run the project.. then also getting the same issue

Comment: why you need flag of no animation in intent.

Comment: i commended both set flags method.. but same problem

Comment: Did you find why you have a black screen ? I have same issue and don't find why...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using launch mode as `singleInstance` which takes a lot of time to rearrange the stack.
Please remove this line from the manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(CurrentclassName.this,TargetclassName.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
   {
     public void onClick(View View)
     {
      {   
  Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, activity1.class);
     intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
       //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);
          overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
       /* Intent i = new Intent(main.this, activity1.class);
        startActivity(i);   */
        // startActivity(new Intent(main.this, activity1.class)));
       }

Comment: why u call intent three time boss when ever u call first intent then it will go to your next activity and u have to make one resource for that means create view. i think u understand coz in click view u wrote more it not necessary  just call these two line  Intent i = new Intent(CurrentclassName.this,TargetclassName.class);
                startActivity(i);

Comment: i pasted three different types of codes which i tried.. i tried with all these three methods separately not together..

Comment: and still u not able to go in second class first time only

Comment: my problem is if i click the image it is showing current activity for a while and then showing black screen and then moving to the respective activity..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40253/discussion-between-bhanu-sharma-and-all-is-well)

Answer (score 0):

1) It sounds you are testing on emulator. They are slow and take some time to load new activity, meanwhile blank screen shows. Running it on real device will solve the problem.

2) May be you are loading some data in onCreate of next activity. If you do, do it in a thread or Async task.

Comment: Am testing this on real device only.. other than click listener i don't have anything in on create

Comment: And what are you doing in Activity2 you are calling?

Comment: I am talking about activity you are calling by clicking image

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't post that code.. it is an activity which contains list of images..

Comment: Thats it, list of images take time to load. Load that list in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` before `startActivity(intent);`

This works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with this but the same issue.. first showing the same page and then black screen and then showing the respective activity..

Comment: You have added after startactivity(intent).

Answer (score 0):

Do simple trick in your style.xml file :
just add `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`
 and also check your `onCreate()` method. Be sure it's not heavily loaded and everytime before you load activity that means before `startActivity(intent);` add `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*I fixed that black screen issue thanks to 'Maulik'.*

As he said:

> First, add next line to your theme preferences at **styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

> Then, before you call **startActivity()**,  you should call

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

or

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.your_custom_anim1, R.anim.your_custom_anim2);
```